# How to pivot this dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this pandas dataframe:

```
product  espec   desc
   1     color   blue
   2     color   blue
   3     size      S
   2     size      M
   2     fabric  cotton
   1     size      S
...
```

And I need to transform into this one:

```
product   color   size  fabric
   1      blue     S      null
   2      blue     M    cotton
   3      null     S     null
```

I've already done using 'for' to go through the dataframe and construct another one, but as the original dataframe is to big and it is taking more than one hour. So, I read about the pandas functions **pivot** and **pivot_table** and I believe it could solve this problem easily. But I'm not getting the parameters right. It always into something strange.

Do anyone know a easy way to make this transformation?

Comment: `new_df = df.pivot(*df).rename_axis(None, axis=1).reset_index()` if you need reindex : `new_df = new_df.reindex(columns=['product', 'color',  'size',  'fabric'])`

Comment: What means the * in front of df?

Comment: Check `[*df]`....